# Не могу сделать редирект на другую страницу.

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Есть таблица с записями, по нажатию на запись должна открываться новая страница с возможностью редактирования.

```
foreach (var t in Model)
            {
                <tr class="task-row-link" title="Edit" data-link="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = t.Id })">
                    <td class="centered"><p>@t.Id</p></td>
                    <td class="centered"><p>@t.Title</p></td>
                </tr>
            }
```

До метода действие не доходит, но если в ручную вбить url .../Edit/1 все работает.

Comment: Так где ж ссылка-то, которая будет открывать новую страницу? Оформите тег <a href='@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = t.Id })'>...</a>

Comment: @СергейПолушин я хочу чтобы вся строка была кликабельной, попробовал так
<tr class="task-row-link" title="Edit" href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = t.Id })">
 но тоже не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вышел из ситуации так :

```
$('tr[data-link]').on('click', function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('a,input,button')) {
        window.location = $(this).attr('data-link');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Средствами только html не получится из строки сделать ссылку, так как тег `tr` нельзя оборачивать в тег ссылки.

Добавьте немного `javascript`)

С использованием jQuery:

```
foreach (var t in Model)
            {
                <tr class="task-row-link" title="Edit" data-link="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = t.Id })">
                    <td class="centered"><p>@t.Id</p></td>
                    <td class="centered"><p>@t.Title</p></td>
                </tr>
            }
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".task-row-link").click(function() {
            window.location = $(this).data("link");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, добавил jQuery только немного по другому.